# Воскрешение - воскресение

Tags: паронимы

В данном коротком предложении как хочешь, так и понимай?

> Птица Феникс – символ Воскрешения.

Кто не верит - чуть подробнее:

> ...На ветвях дерева слева снова сидит сверкающая птичка в лазоревом
>   нимбе. На неё указывает Христос и словно на неё указывает вся
>   смысловая и художественная композиция храмовых мозаик. Птица Феникс –
>   символ Воскрешения.

Comment: Воскрешение - от "воскрешать (кого-л. со знанием дела)", от "воскреснуть/воскресать" (как Христос) - Воскресение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По поводу *словно*: будто сомнение посетило автора. Насчёт второго *указывает*: оно намекает, что слова закончились. Композиция мозаик... Есть ли она, такая общая композиция?

«Птица Феникс – символ Воскрешения». Почему с прописной? Слово в отрыве от Его имени — обычное слово, не высокое. Нимб имеет «наш» синоним — свет. Может быть так?

*На ветвях дерева — сверкающая птица в лазоревом свете. На неё указывает Христос и на ней строится смысловая и художественная композиция храмовой мозаики. Птица Феникс – символ Его Воскрешения.*

Comment: Ой, нет! Вот добавил слово - и внёс орфографическую ясность: *Птица Феникс – символ Его Воскрешения*. У меня-то этого всепроясняющего слова нет. *Его* никто не воскрешал, Он сам воскрес. Поэтому с добавлением определения будет: *Птица Феникс – символ Его Воскре**с**ения*.